# Flutter: How to pass parameter to Future async function

Tags: asynchronous, parameters, flutter

I have to pass parameter to Future async function from floatingbutton

My Codes like

```
FloatingActionButton(
                     onPressed: getImageFromCam,
                      tooltip: 'Pick Image',
                      child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
                     ),
```

And

```
     Future getImageFromCam() async { // for camera
        var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
        setState(() {
          _image = image;
        });
}
```

It is multiple button so i have to pass index to async function.

Can anyone please help to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Sathish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot explicitly specify any argument when using a [tear-off](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/402561). Instead, you should manually define a closure:

```dart
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () => getImageFromCam(index),
  tooltip: 'Pick Image',
  child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
);

...

Future<void> getImageFromCam(int index) async {
  // Do whatever you want with `index`.
  final image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  setState(() => _image = image);
}
```